# how to convert the sharepoint recurrencedata field (xml) to ical format (vis versa)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How do I make both conversion from recurrence data field to ical format and 
 ical to  recurrence data field?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link, not a complete solution but a good place to start with:
http://aspnetguru.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/understanding-the-sharepoint-calendar-and-how-to-export-it-to-ical-format/